# Keeping object placement consistent in officer package

Tags: r, officer

I am having trouble with the officer package. Everytime I add a slide template to the template object, the indices seem to change. What is the logic on the indices? Is there one?

In ReporteRs, the index was which order you added the placeholder object. Is there any similar logic for officer?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Comment: @MrFlick a reproducible example will be difficult because the issue arises when you do things outside of R (e.g. adding a slide to a powerpoint template) but I will try.